# Oracle SQL vs Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to learn Oracle SQL for work and am very tempted by the O'Reilly book 'Oracle PL/SQL Programming' as it has been so highly reviewed. However, I am unclear as to whether or not PL/SQL is a different language to SQL or if it is just a superset or if it something else. Can  someone please help me here? Thanks.

Comment: also see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Oracle-SQL-and-PL-SQL#

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQL is a data query and manipulation langauge.  PL/SQL is a procedural programming language.

PL/SQL is Turing complete language, with syntax for building complicated programmes.  It also has a large number of libraries which give it a great range of capabilties.  However, undoubtedly its main use is building stored procedures which embed SQL statements for retrieving and working with data.  So to that extent PL/SQL is a superset of SQL.

Although in earlier versions of the database the PL/SQL SQL engine lagged behind the database engine so some SQL functionality was not available in PL/SQL.  Since 9i Oracle has mad a concerted effort to keep the two in step, and its pretty hard to find anything we can do in pure SQL which we cannot also do in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 5):

it is a superset.

all of SQL plus some PROCEDURAL extensions - so you can have variables, loops, conditional logic etc.